# How to use .address function in order to delete a row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of .xls files that have 6 rows of junk at the beginning of the files and 1 line with the text "Not Classified" in an arbitrary row of column A. I have the below code which deletes the first 6 rows and then finds the cell with the proper text, but I don't know how to then select that row, since my understanding is the Find function is returning like A10 and I do not know how to split the reference in order to Select row 10.

I believe the address function should be able to help in this regard but I am having trouble getting it to work. In the above path is the variable that stores the location of my files and x is the cell with the offending text.

```
Do while files <>""
    Workbooks.Open(path & files).ActiveSheet.Rows("1:6").Delete
    Set x = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("Not Classified")
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
        x.Clear 
        'Obviously this only clears the cell with the offending text and I 
        'want to delete the whole row
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
    files = Dir()
Loop
```

I believe the address function should be able to help in this regard but I am having trouble getting it to work. In the above path is the variable that stores the location of my files and x is the cell with the offending text.

Comment: `x` is a `Range`. You can do `x.EntireRow.Delete`. You don't need an address.

Comment: x.EntireRow.Delete

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strSearchValue As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngPosition As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        strSearchValue = "Not Classified"
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Find lastrow to create a range. No need to use thw whole column.

        Set rngSearch = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) '<- Set your range

        Set rngPosition = rngSearch.Find(strSearchValue) '<- Find the position of the value

        If Not rngPosition Is Nothing Then '<- To avoid error check if the position is not nothing

            MsgBox rngPosition.Address '<- Message box with the address

        End If

        'How to delete row a row. Have in mind that when you delete you must go backwards - from bottom to top to avoid breaking indexing.
        .Rows(rngPosition.Row).EntireRow.Delete

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could produce a Union of both ranges (rows 1:6 and the row containing "Not Classified") then delete them.

```
  dim r as variant

  Do while files <>""
    with Workbooks.Open(path & files)
      with .worksheets(1)  '<~~ know what worksheet you're dealing with
        r = application.match("Not Classified", .range("A:A"), 0)

        if iserror(r) then
            .range("A1:A6").entirerow.Delete
        else
            .range("A1:A6, A" & r).entirerow.Delete
        end if

      end with
      .Close savechanges:=True
    end with
    files = Dir()
  Loop
```